# C++ using namespaces into same namespace nested

Tags: c++, header, namespaces

Let's say I have a namespace:

```
namespace UI
{
}
```

And I have another namespace:

```
namespace Domain
{
}
```

Now let's say in the Domain namespace I also have a UI namespace that is specific for that domain.

```
namespace Domain
{
    namespace UI
    {
    }
}
```

Is it possible to import the global UI namespace into the domain UI namespace without importing it in the Domain namespace? I know using namespace is often not a good idea but conceptually the domain UI namespace should be both in the global UI namespace and in the domain namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible ways are  namespace alias or use the entire namespace UI into Domain::UI. In both cases theres a way for access it from Domain namespace.

Examples:

```
namespace UI {
    class Test {

    };
}

namespace Domain {

}

namespace Domain {
    namespace UI {
        namespace _UI = ::UI;

        struct Test2 {
            _UI::Test param;
        };
    }
}

namespace Domain2 {

    namespace UI {
        using namespace ::UI;

        struct Test2 {
            Test param;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, exactly, use ::UI when referencing to the global namespace.

Comment: Wow you can have namespace aliases didn't even know that. One more question if I do the 2nd solution the header, does this it import the global UI  for all uses of the domain UI namespace?

Comment: No, only works in files including "using namespace ::UI" or files including a header with the using. Namespace in C++ not work like for example packages in Go. If you don't have a header defining something, theres no visibiltiy for that.